# MySQL Online Backup Method

Tags: mysql, backup

I was looking around for the best method to do an online backup of MySQL stored data.

I was no completely satisfied with the previous answers.

Im not asking for a specific method for now, I asking which "road" do you consider best.

Preferably it should be free and as easy as possible.

Comment: Please clarify "online backup"--does that mean hot standby (another MySQL instance), or the contents of mysqldump available online?

Comment: Hot standby, point-in-time recovery, snapshots or pure archiving indeed.

Comment: @OMG Ponies I was definitely not clear enough! What i ment was on the line of mysqldumpt etc

Comment: @Trufa: those were not suggestions, those were unfortunately elaborations on OMG's question, about which of those you actually needed.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, the thing is I understand VERY little about the subject and misinterpreted the comment, thanks for the clarifications, I havent hace time yet to read about it in depth, thats why I posted this question to have a picture of where to start! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juan, if you cannot have downtime for table/row locking during backups, then I would consider implementing either MySQL replication or DRBD so that you have an "offline" host dedicated to backups, reporting, etc. Either way, once you have an offline, yet consistent copy of your master host, you can go down the road of mysqldumps, lvm snapshots, whatever your situation calls for.

Replication:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

DRBD:
http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/drbd.html

MySQL LVM snapshots:
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/21/using-lvm-for-mysql-backup-and-replication-setup/

Comment: Thanks randy, I think the most viable immediately is LVM snapshots, I will take a thorough look it it and maybe later post some more specific questions. Thanks again!!

Comment: LVM snapshots are thoroughly unreliable. It may work, it may work a while, but theres a very real chance the DB is in erroneous state if you try to recover with a backup taken _while there were still processes running on it_. It is a a teeny better then people just copying the datadir, but it has definite flaws.